# How to echo other field (column) value with the help of id value from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP web pages with page ids such as following example:

```
www.mysite.com/page.php?id=150

www.mysite.com/page.php?id=151

www.mysite.com/page.php?id=152
```

and so on...

The mysql table is having two columns with field names and values, for example:

`id` = `150`

`email` = `test@mysite.com`

I am able to retrieve page `id` with the help of: `echo $_GET['id'];`

How do I fetch the email based on the `GET` parameter? For example for `www.mysite.com/page.php?id=150` I would like to echo the email `test@mysite.com` on `page.php`.

Comment: Please add your relevant code in the question to so everyone can understand and not assume ;)

Comment: I can't wait so I'll just guess: you could use a form with a method and then fetch the data from it, that is _If_ you're not trying in that direction already

Comment: either do &email=abc@gmail.com or fetch it from database if you have there.

Comment: Email address is already in database. I need to fetch it from there.

Comment: Show your current PHP code, or are you just asking how to fetch in general? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/

Comment: @chris85 I have used: <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM table_name WHERE id ='$id'"); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo $id; } ?> This is not working.

Comment: You never assigned `$id` to anything. Also you shouldn't be using the `mysql_` functions anymore.

Comment: @Chandrakant success, no success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, from your provided code you need to address the column you want the data from.

```
<?php 
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM table_name WHERE id =$id"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
     echo $row['email'];
     //$emails[] = $row['email']; or if you want to use them later store them.
} 
?>
```

You also should update to the `PDO` or `mysqli` drivers. `mysql_` is out of date. It also can't handle prepared statements which is what you should be using. This will prevent SQL injections. I've cast the user input to an integer here to avoid the injection hole.

Answer (score 0):

*How do I fetch and echo related email field on page.php?*

That (to me) seems like you're trying to fetch the input field, if so this could be one way:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "page.php">
Enter the Email:
<input type = "text" name = "email">
<input type = "hidden" name = "check">
<input type = "submit" value = "Goto Next Page">
</form>
```

and then on page.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['check'])){

echo $email = $_POST['email'];

$que = "SELECT email from tablename WHERE email = '$email'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $que);
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Moving from from the comments, this is what you should try:

```
<?php 
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM table_name WHERE id ='$id'"); 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row['email'];
 // write more this to fetch the required data
echo $row['Your_Next_Column_Name_Here']; 
} 
?>
```

> Notice: This will work for the time but it is strictly advised to move
>   to either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Email address is already in database. I need to fetch it from there.

Comment: either use php or ajax to fetch it from db just go through http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: @Chandrakant Create a PHP connection with MYSQL and shoot a query somewhat like I posted in the answer and you're good to go.

Comment: Please write the PHP code to fetch it from database?

Comment: No, this answer opens the OP to SQL injections. 1. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php 2. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I think any mysql query which uses id to fetch and echo the relevant email address.

Comment: @Chandrakant your table must have a column for `email` and you can then shoot a query to get the desired email. somewhat like: `"SELECT email FROM tablename WHERE id = '5'";`

Comment: Table does have column for email. id is not fixed, it varies from page to page. I have other pages such as: www.mysite.com/page.php?id=151, www.mysite.com/page.php?id=152 and so on.

Comment: @Chandrakant Not an issue, Simply use the _incoming_ one `"SELECT email FROM tablename WHERE id = '$id'";`

Comment: @Chandrakant what do you want to echo? the id? `echo $id;` would do it.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari it didn't worked. I have used: <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM table_name WHERE id ='$id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{

 echo $id; 
}

?>

Comment: @Chandrakant what did you use? And what did not work?